# Weibel Exercise $1.1.4$ About $\hom(\mathbb{Z}/n, C)$

Tags: homological-algebra

I am reading Weibel's Introduction to Homological Algebra.  I have come across this exercise:
$$
\text{If $C$ is a chain complex and $H_n(\hom(\mathbb{Z}/n, C)) = 0$, then $H_n(C) = 0$.}
$$

It seems that this is false as stated.  I can take the chain complex
$$
\cdots \stackrel{0}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/5 \stackrel{0}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/5 \stackrel{0}{\to} \cdots
$$
Then the chain complex $\hom(\mathbb{Z}/6, C)$ has all homology groups $0$, since there are no nontrivial homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/6$ to $\mathbb{Z}/5$.  But, all the homology groups of $C$ are $\mathbb{Z}/5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He doesn’t write $\mathbb{Z}/n$. He writes $Z_n$, which is the kernel of the degree $n$ differential of the complex $C$, and nothing to do with the integers mod $n$.

Comment: Thanks.  I really dislike that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is used for $\mathbb{Z}/n$ sometimes.  The exercise is now very straightforward.